# Post an NSArray from swift to PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, nsarray

I tried to post an array of integers to my server so PHP can work with that. My problem is that it doesn't work. I just began programming with PHP so I don't have much knowledge...

Here is my swift code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: myURL)!
    var session: NSURLSession!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    do {
        dataNotice = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestForNotice) as! [Notice]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    //create array of existing IDs
    var noticeIDs: [Int] = [Int]()
    for var i = 0; i < dataNotice.count; i++ {

        noticeIDs.append(dataNotice[i].id as! Int)
        print("Notice ID: " + String(dataNotice[i].id))
    }

    let postString = "server=\(server)&username=\(username)&password=\(password)&database=\(database)&noticeIDs=\(noticeIDs)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)

    task.resume()
```

**UPDATE**
And this is my PHP code to catch the array:

```
    <?php

$method = $_POST['method'];
$db_server = $_POST['server'];
$db_benutzer = $_POST['username'];
$db_passwort = $_POST['password'];
$db_name = $_POST['database'];
$applicationNotices = $_POST['noticeIDs'];

$databaseNotices;

$con=mysqli_connect($db_server,$db_benutzer,$db_passwort,$db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Notice`";
$sqlID = "SELECT `ID` FROM `Notice`";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    if ($resultID = mysqli_query($con, $sqlID)) {
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();
        $idArray = array();
        $tempIDArray = array();

        while($rowID = $resultID->fetch_object())
        {
            $tempIDArray = intval($rowID->ID);
            array_push($idArray, $tempIDArray);
        }

        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        $neededNotices = array_diff($idArray, $applicationNotices);

        $array = array_map('intval', $neededNotices);
        $array = implode("','",$array);

        $finalSql = "SELECT * FROM `Notice` WHERE `ID` IN ('".$array."')";
        if ($finalResult = mysqli_query($con, $finalSql)) {
            $finalArray = array();
            $tempFinalArray = array();

            while($finalRow = $finalResult->fetch_object())
            {
                $tempFinalArray = $finalRow;
                array_push($finalArray, $tempFinalArray);
            }

            echo json_encode($finalArray);
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This code should take the existing ids in my Core Data database and transfer these to my Server for comparing this ids with the ids of my sql database and returning all entries that aren't currently in the application.

If I run the code I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' (0x110469780) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x11046a978).

How can I transfer the data properly to my Server?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Well for one I wouldn't pass the username and password and host name every time because that's excessive networking even if it seems small and its less secure. Secondly, your set your HTTPMethod as POST so in your php code you should be retrieving the value from `$_POST` instead of request.